# Why can't I set the partition size more than 3,99 GiB in Fedora 25?

Tags: fedora, partition, system-installation, size

I'm a new linux user (Fedora, LXDE).

When I was installing Fedora 25 (before the last kernel update to 4.11.8, if that'd be useful), I saw I cannot set the partition (?) size more than 3,99 GiB. When I try to do that (even just 4 GiB or 4096 MiB), **it automatically shrinks to 8 MiB** (similar values in other attempts). It also happend when I was installing Fedora the second time (same installer and computer). And each time the installer showed me I have enough space to increase partition size (although sometimes it was less than 1024 MiB).

I think it may be related to my machine's specification - so say what you need, I'm going to post it. Maybe it's even (just) a bug? Or am I missing something (important)?

---

UPDATE 1: **The filesystem** I chose during installation was **ext4**.

---

UPDATE 2: **It seems it's a bug** - when I was today installing Fedora Workstation (not LXDE) on a different computer, on a different hard disk with over 80 GB free, it cannot let me assign more than 3,99 GiB again.

But, I noticed two things. **First**, the installer was behaving like it was **wrapping** the size. When I tried to set 4 GiB, it showed me 8 MiB, when 5 GiB - it showed 1,01 GiB, when 6 GiB - it showed 2,01 GiB, when 7 GiB - it showed 3,01 GiB, when 8 GiB - **it showed 8 MiB again**, when 9 GiB - it showed 1,01 GiB again... (I'm not sure I remember exact numbers) **Second** (which probably also took place earlier), in the first step I chose manual partitioning, **but in the next step I chose automatic partitioning**. Then, when I tried to set the size of the auto-created partition (I tried `/` and `/home`), it allowed me to set less, but more than 3,99 (e.g. from 20 GiB to 10 GiB). And, when I removed e.g. `/` and then created it again manually, I cannot set more than 3,99 again.

Comment: That's weird. Can you post screenshots of this happening?

Comment: What filesystem type are you using?

Comment: @mattdm, I've updated my question with the filesystem. As for screenshot - I don't know how could I make a screenshot from the installer (running from USB). To clarify, I am unable to run Fedora Live, just the installer directly. Maybe is there a way to run the installer from running system?

Comment: During installation, press `Shift+Print Screen` -- this will save a screenshot to `/root/anaconda-screenshots`.

Comment: @mattdm, you mean I have to install it once again? If no, I cannot find this directory. Please, not the 4th time. ; - ) Except Windows, I have only ~0,5 GiB to use on my hard drive. Maybe I can give you all necessary information some other way? I will try to free some space from Windows, but nothing's guaranteed.

Comment: I'm confused. If you have only half a gigabyte free on your hard drive, how are you creating 3.99GB partitions?

Comment: Oh, I see - to clarify: I'm not writing it from Windows, but from Fedora, if that you mean. If I removed my current Fedora installation, I would have about 11 GiB to use.